# How can HTML assets be download before HTML content has finished dowloading

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, web, pagespeed

I am trying to improve my site load speed. When checking on the network requests, there is something that doesn't make sense to me:

How can the content that is going to be requested (css and js files) is being download before the html content has been downloaded?
I have tried with a hard reload and empty cache from chrome, but this has happened again. Morover, the files seem to be dowload from the server and not from the cache.

[image]

Another thing I don't get, is why chrome is pating the bar chart almost all with blue, when the majority of the time is waiting for the server to respond (TTFB).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possibilities:

1. The HTML doesn't download all at once. It's possible for the server to send part of the page, pause, then send the rest. If the part that's sent first contains references to CSS, JS, image, font, or other files, the browser can start downloading those files as soon as it sees them referenced.
2. HTTP 2.0 supports "server push", a scheme where the web server can indicate to the client through HTTP headers that it should start downloading specific other files. Judging from some of the file names in your network tab, you're using Cloudflare; they use server push for some features, including "Rocket Loader".

Comment: I have been reading about "server push" and I think chrome should show a "Push" text under the Initiator column. Is that so?